# Unit Testing CIImage Filters

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiimage, ocunit, ciimage

I'm writing an app that allows users to add different filters to images they take with their devices' cameras. While that's working fine and I've been able to add the filters, I want to write unit tests to make sure that the code is working properly.

I started by checking if an image I add a filter to in the test is the same (using the equals function) as an image I add a filter to with my code. This did not lead to any conclusive results.

Then I started by comparing the metadata of the filtered and unfiltered image. There seems to have been no change to the metadata when adding a filter.

Does anyone know of a way to test that a filter has been applied to an image? I would like to write unit tests for my app but this is just driving me nuts.